# Preventing DoS attacks in tomcat 6

Tags: web-services, security, tomcat6

I have exposed a REST service on internet with mobile apps being its client. I want to protect this service from DoS attacks. I am using tomcat 6

Is it possible to configure tomcat to prevent such attacks? If yes How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preety simple, using Web Application Firewall, or mod_security in your proxy. As a second layer of security you can write a custom Valve and deploy it in tomcat. But it should only be additional not primary, because it still consumes memory and cpu. So if it's posiible to let some other app to handle DoS mitigation then its excelent, because your app will only recive legitimate traffic.